# How to get value of an HTML element nested inside other HTML elemnts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML elements as shown below

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="item1" value="AA"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="item2" value="BB"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="item3" value="CC"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract array of values like `[AA,BB,CC]` and IDs like `[1,2,3]` -from item1,item2,item3  using JavaScript and Jquery .How to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var idarray = [];
var valuearray = [];

$("#container input").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   idarray.push($this.attr("id").substring(4));
   valuearray.push($this.val());
});

console.log(idarray);
console.log(valuearray);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DUADQ/)

Comment: instead of $this.attr("value") use  $this.val()

Comment: instead of using `attr()` use `prop()`  
Please have alook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @sanalism ya, copied from the above line

Comment: @asifsid88 in this case `attr` is good because id is a attribute than a runtime property

Answer (score 0):

Loop the inputs, pull the values, parse the item value. Something like this:

```
var ids = [];
var values = [];

$("input").each(function(){
   var input = $(this);
   var value = input.val();
   var id = input.attr("id").replace("item", "");

   ids.push(id);
   values.push(value);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JYnzX/1/) (warning: two alert popups)

Notice the the input value is obtained using `input.val()`, this will ensure that the value retrieved is the current value as entered by the user. If you wanted the attribute `value` (which will not be changed simply by the user typing something else) you could use `input.attr("value")` instead

---

If you have other `input` elements on the page that you do not want to include then you need to be more specific with you selector. For example, if all the desired `input` elements are with the `id="container"` element, then you can use this instead:

```
$("#container input").each(...
```

Comment: If OP has multiple "input" tag in his page then this will result into wrong output

Comment: @asifsid88: yeah... and if the OP changes the inputs to labels it will also be wrong. There are lots of unknowns that could break any of these answers, we can only work with the example code shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vals = [];
var ids = [];
$("#container input").each(function(){
    vals.push($(this).val());
    ids.push($(this).attr("id").replace("item", ""));
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alepac/a6CKX/2/) is the jsfiddle:

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = $('#container').find('input').map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();

var ids = $('#container').find('input').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('id').replace('item','');
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Qhm5J/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = $("input[id^='item']").map(function(i,e){
    return e.id;
});

var values = $("input[id^='item']").map(function(i,e){
    return $(e).val();
});

console.log(ids);
console.log(values);
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RLsCX/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer
http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/8/

```
var ids = []
var values = []
$('#container input[type=text]').each(function() {
ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
values.push($(this).val())
})
alert(ids)
alert(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrId = [], arrVal = [];
$("input[type='text']").each(function(){//find input text
  if(this.id && this.id.indexOf("item")===0){//check id starts with item
    arrId.push(this.id.replace("item",""));//push id
    arrVal.push(this.value);//push value
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jGNy7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valuesArray = []
        , idsArray = [];
    $('#container').children().each(function() {
        valuesArray.push($(this).children().children().val());
        idsArray.push($(this).children().children().prop('id').substr(4));
    });
    alert(valuesArray);
    alert(idsArray);
});
```